# How to use ReactJS to give immediate feedback to user before a long operation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

NOTE: Marking Michael Cox's answer below correct, but you should read the discussion underneath the answer as well, which illustrates that componentDidMount is apparently called BEFORE browser render.

I have a ReactJS app, and when the user clicks a button, I'd like to change the button text to "Working..." so that the user can see that the app is working on their request. AFTER the updated button has been rendered, then and only then, do I want to actually start the operation.

My first attempt was to use componentDidUpdate. AFAIK, it shouldn't be called until AFTER rendering. But here is my attempt, and you can see the button never changes (open up console to help it take long enough). https://jsfiddle.net/joepinion/0s78e2oj/6/

```
class LongOperationButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        opInProgress: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    let btnTxt = "Start Operation";
    if(this.state.opInProgress) {
      btnTxt = "Working...";
    }

    return(
        <button 
        onClick={()=>this.startOp()}
      >
        {btnTxt}
      </button>
    );
  }

  startOp() {
    if(!this.state.opInProgress) {
      this.setState({opInProgress: true});
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.opInProgress) {
      this.props.op();
      this.setState({opInProgress: false});
    }
  }
}

function takeALongTime() {
    for(let i=1;i<=2000;i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LongOperationButton op={takeALongTime} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Next attempt I tried using the callback of setState. Seems less correct because it bypasses componentShouldUpdate, but worth a shot: https://jsfiddle.net/joepinion/mj0e7gdk/14/

Same result, the button doesn't update.

What am I missing here???

Comment: `for(let i=1;i<=2000;i++)` => you're blocking the rendering loop so nothing will happen. You need to do your long operation in an asynchronous way, or using workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

laurent's comment is dead on. You're code is executing this.props.op, then immediately updating the state. `TakeALongTime` needs to signal when it's done.

```
function takeALongTime() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  });
}
```

and `componentDidUpdate` needs to wait until `op` is done before setting the state.

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.opInProgress) {
      this.props.op().then(() => {
        this.setState({opInProgress: false});
      });
    }
  }
```

(This is going off of your first example.)

---

You could also do this with callbacks.

```
function takeALongTime(cb) {
    setTimeout(cb, 1000);
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  if(this.state.opInProgress) {
    var parentThis = this;
    this.props.op(function() {
      parentThis.setState({opInProgress: false});
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The difference in your code seems to be using the setTimeout method as your callback function illustrates. If I add a promise but keep the looping code (because that's more what my code is like, a series of instructions that takes a couple seconds) it still doesn't work. So do I need to do a timeout just to sort of bump my code behind the dom rendering?

Comment: setTimeout is just my easy way of acting like the computer is doing some work. You could do it like this ```function takeALongTime(cb) {
 for(let i=1;i<=200000;i++) {
   console.log(i);
  };
  cb();
}```  BUT when I do that it doesn't update the component until the work is done. Will your work be done on the server or in the browser?

Comment: It's a fully frontend app. I'm thinking what this problem illustrates is that componentDidMount resolves after the virtual DOM is updated but not necessarily before the browser's DOM. Would you agree? If so add that fact to your answer above (gets to the heart of the matter) and I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: I think the issue is `componentDidUpdate` runs before `render`, so you're actually making the computer work and complete the action before rendering the updated component.

Comment: That causes me to reinterpret this doc https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate which says for componentDidUpdate, "Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated." I always took that to mean the browser DOM was up-to-date, but maybe it means the opposite - the internal state and (maybe) virtual DOM is updated but not the browser DOM.